Creating new Vue project with Vuetify not working
I have been following this guide and all its steps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=To5XzHlTS_E. However, when I run the "npm run dev" it seems like the styling is not applied correctly, please see image below. Why is my styles not working as expected even if I did all steps as mentioned in the video?


You need to add your code that you have tried, so that it will be easier to help you.

This is an old video for Vue2. Rather please read the documentation of Vue on how to get started + the documentation from Vuetify.

The problem with the YouTube instructions is that vue add vuetify doesn't add vuetify() to the array of plugins in vite.config.js.
It should look like this:
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/tree/next/packages/vite-plugin
import vuetify from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(), vuetify()
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})

This will resolve the issue, but be warned that the vue command also doesn't install the latest version of Vuetify 3 (which has been out of beta for over a year!).  Creating a new project following the latest Vuetify documentation won't have any of these problems.  Lesson here is to always check official documentation since YouTube videos can quickly become outdated.
